# Fitting parameter b of the Gamma distribution from mean, 95% in Python

Tags: python-3.x, wolfram-mathematica, gamma-distribution

This Mathematica function finds parameter b of the Gamma distribution, 
  given mean and 95% values and scaled by the mean [Mu];
The two values bracket [Beta] makes it fast and there is a restriction for max pg95= 5.8[Mu]* gb[[Mu]*, p95*]. 
I need to translate this code into Python:

```
gb[\[Mu]_, p95_] := Block[{p = Min[p95/\[Mu], 5.8]},
\[Mu] FindRoot[CDF[GammaDistribution[1/\[Beta], \[Beta]], p] - .95 == 0,
  {\[Beta], 1, If[p == 1, 1.1, p]}][[1, 2]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you cannot find exactly equivalent gamma functions you ought to be able to translate `gb` with SciPy's integration and root finding functions.  The functions required can be obtained, e.g. (illustrating with some demo values)

[image]

For example

[image]

As you can see, the code constructed from the more basic functions produces the same answer, albeit more slowly.

***Code***

```
gamma[z_] := \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(z - 1\)] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-t\)] \[DifferentialD]t\)\)
gamma[a_, z0_, z1_] := \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(z0\), \(z1\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(a - 1\)] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-t\)] \[DifferentialD]t\)\)
gammaregularized[a_, z1_] := gamma[a, 0, z1]/gamma[a]
cdf[\[Beta]_, p_] := 
 Piecewise[{{gammaregularized[1/\[Beta], p/\[Beta]], p > 0}}]
p = 1.2;
FindRoot[cdf[\[Beta], p] - .95, {\[Beta], 1, If[p == 1, 1.1, p]}]
FindRoot[CDF[GammaDistribution[1/\[Beta], \[Beta]], 
   p] - .95, {\[Beta], 1, If[p == 1, 1.1, p]}]
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I have a few more Mathematica functions which I need translated into Python. Could you help me with this task? I could send you the code before so you could think about it. That’s my contact information Julia.derx@gmail.com

Comment: You can often find information on higher level functions in the documentation and by symbolic evaluation, as I demonstrated.  If you need help breaking down a higher level function I would suggest you ask here: https:\\mathematica.stackexchange.com.  It is mainly a Mathematica site, not for Python, but finding the basic functions in a higher level Mathematica function should be within the topic scope.