# Is there any Python function to define the 'findroot function' of Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: python-3.x, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to rewrite some codes from Mathematica into Python. Is there a way to describe Findroot function in Python 3.x?
here is the code from wolfram mathematica!

```
[Mu]FindRoot[CDF[GammaDistribution[1/b, b], p] - .95 == 0, {b, 1, If[p == 1, 1.1, p]}][[1, 2]]]
#b is for beta
```

Comment: Looks similar to this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/55168437/879601

Comment: Python people will likely ask you what FindRoot does. Please explain this in the question. Here's detailed documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview.html

Comment: With FindRoot function in Wolfram Mathematica one can find the roots of a given function. I guess the same function in python is the fsolve from the scipy.optimize.

Comment: the function above is the CDF gamma distribution. As I can read from this WF code, x0 is 1.0, and x1 is the second statement with 'if' for b. But it is still not clear completely.